# Using crosstab and adding new value to a column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a function (sae_rel_data())that returns a result like the one showing in the picture. I am trying to return the result as table event_crf_id, description, value, CBID instead. So I would have to identify the CBID value and assign that value to all other rows that has the same evet_crf_id in another column named CBID.

For example CBID= 60051 has event_crf_id=444

```
event_crf_id; description;        value;            CBID
   444;          "CBID";          "60051";         "60051"
   444;         "Month";           "09";           "60051"
   444;         "Day";             "27";           "60051"
   444;         "Year";            "2016";         "60051"
...
```

How can it be done? I am using postgresql

[image]

Comment: put function definition instead of that big screenshot. you need to define additional column in return set in short.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result I wanted by using breaking down my code and saving portions of it into a function and then applying inner join

```
   SELECT cbid, description, value FROM (
    SELECT test.event_crf_id, description, test.value, id_table.cbi FROM sae_rel_data() test
   INNER JOIN (SELECT event_crf_id, value as cbid FROM sae_rel_data() where description='CBID') id_table
    ON id_table.event_crf_id=test.event_crf_id )relevant
```